# Pjsip on CentOS 7 problems on building CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, centos7, pjsip

I'm trying to build my C++ project which includes Pjsip library on Centos 7 using CMake and Qt IDE  without success. I built Pjsip for Centos using steps defined in readme.txt :

```
./configure
make dep && make
```

After that configured CMakeLists.txt with this configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt)
project(hello-pjsip)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -DSERVER_REMOTE_LOGGING -ggdb -Wno-unused-local-typedefs")

# Set the compilers as the default GCC for Centos 7 doesn't support all C++11 features
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/bin/g++)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/bin/gcc)

# PJ library

include_directories(~/pjproject/pjlib/include)
link_directories(~/pjproject/pjlib/lib)

include_directories(~/pjproject/pjlib-util/include)
link_directories(~/pjproject/pjlib-util/lib)

include_directories(~/pjproject/pjnath/include)
include_directories(~/pjproject/pjnath/src)
link_directories(~/pjproject/pjnath/lib)

# Source files
set (SOURCE_FILES
      main.h
      main.cpp
    )

# Library files
set (LIBRARY_FILES 
     pj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     pjnath-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     pjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    )

add_executable(hello-pjsip ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(hello-pjsip ${LIBRARY_FILES})
```

After running build received these errors:

[image: Build errors]

I tried to recompile pjsip library with different options but no success, same errors every time. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PJ had bug, solved 5 months ago. This solved problem:
 https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/5599